# VIM - Installing vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people with package manager (vim 8.1)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm new to vim, running it in iTerm2 Mac, write clojure code and would like to install 
https://github.com/tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people

The installation instructions there are, assuming `pathogen.vim`:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people.git
git clone git://github.com/guns/vim-sexp.git
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat.git
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-surround.git
```

Now, I'm a new user, and was told to use vim's own package manager (vim 8.1). I was able to put vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people itself, put I'm not sure, what the correct directory structure for the bundled plugins should look like, in other words, what pathogen would build out of the beforementioned bundle ... any help for a newbie?

Answer (score 2):

The directories where Vim 8+ will look for package plug-ins are named `pack/identifier/start`, where you can use any "identifier" you like as your package name (the feature is built so you can have multiple "packages", which are essentially collections of plug-ins.)

For simplicity, you can keep calling your package `bundle`, for a parallel with pathogen.

You can use:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start
cd ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people.git
git clone git://github.com/guns/vim-sexp.git
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat.git
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-surround.git
```

Also give some consideration to [minpac](https://github.com/k-takata/minpac), which is a package manager built on top of Vim 8's native package feature, so it will use load plug-ins through Vim's native packages, but it will help you install and update plug-ins into the appropriate package directories. (In other words, addressing exactly the need you're asking about here.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, help in the beginning is appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelMeixner You might want to take a look at the [Vi & Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for your questions about Vim!

Comment: Will do! Additional newbie question: while trying to install minpac I created .vim/.vimrc with the proposed beginning: "packadd minpac
call minpac#init() ...", but when sourcing .vimrc I get "command not found: packadd" ... what's this?

Comment: @MichaelMeixner I suggest you ask separate questions for follow ups, that works much better here... Not sure what could be causing that, `packadd` should be available in Vim 8 or later, make sure you're actually in Vim 8! (Use `:version` from inside Vim, or `vim --version` from the shell.) Also, I believe the correct path is `~/.vim/vimrc` without the dot in the beginning of the file name (only directory has a dot in the name.)

Comment: Also make sure you're sourcing it in Vim and not in the shell! I believe `command not found` is what the shell would say... Vim says `E492: Not an editor command` for invalid Vimscript commands...

Comment: will heed advice - thanks! yes I tried to source in the shell (silly)